# Identifying functional groups with labile hydrogens from IR hydrogen bonding region

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrogen-bond, ir-spectroscopy

Here is the $\pu{2000-4000 cm^{-1}}$ spectral region (known for showing hydrogen bonding interactions, $\ce{-H\bond{<-}X-}$) for three different compounds, each showing a different functional group:

[image]

where

- A is a carboxylic acid,
- B is an amine, and
- C is an alcohol.

Is it possible to uniquely identify these three compounds just from peak positions, shapes, and intensities within this window?

Comment: Not quite sure anyone is really going to understand what your exact problem is? Do you have any specific reason to doubt your choices? If so, what was your line of thought in solving these? Give us specifics - we are not here to do your homework.

Comment: @Bob I just looked at pictures of graphs of similar groups and assigned them based on shape. We weren't told if we should do anything more analytic than that.

Comment: I would suggest reading your textbook to figure out why specific patterns appear in a spectrum.

Comment: @Bob I remember Pretsch et al., Structure Determination of Organic Compounds (http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-540-93810-1) includes even "hypothetical IR spectra".  To clarify this:  how the spectrum should look like if *only* this functional group (amine, aldehyde, ester, ...) were present; presenting the whole range from about 4000 to down 600 (or so) 1/cm; followed by examples. Still today I find this presentation more instructive and helpful than "the simplier tables" alone.

Comment: @Buttonwood Then they're based off the max's.

Comment: @Buttonwood  A is a carboxylic acid because of a max at 3000. B is an amine because max is below 3000. C s an alcohol because max is at 2900.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you do not know that the title of your question already contains an important key to interpret IR-spectra: not only to inspect rather small, isolated regions of the spectrum, but to see the spectrum as a whole.  By doing so, you have to watch out for additional absorption bands that were *equally* providing evidence for one, or the other structure; by scrutinizing both the position ($\tilde\nu$), shape, and relative intensity of the absorption bands in question.

As an example: is there evidence for a carbonyl group, indicative for the acid?

Why?  Because -- depending on the mode of data collection (e.g., transmission in a matrix of a KBr pellet, or neat film by [ATR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attenuated_total_reflectance)) the shape of the spectra recorded may differ.  In contrast to 1H NMR, IR offers you a view on structural elements .and. the whole molecule.  Then, indeed, IR spectroscopy may offer much insight.

---

P.S.:  From the baseline of the spectra shown it is *likely* the data were recorded on a ATR-FT-IR spectrometer.  If you look into the data recorded, you will find each point is typically about 0.43 wavenumbers a part from the next one.  Hence it may be more sound to perform the "peak pic" / stating the barycentre of the absorption bands only by whole wavenumbers, *without* two digits behind the decimal point ([significant figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures)).